# Find the normal subgroup $N$ if $G = S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

I need a little help to understand this answer.

Let $G$ be a group, and $N$ be the subgroup generated by elements of the form $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$, where $a,b \in G$. I've shown that this subgroup is normal in $G$ and that the quotient group $ G / N $ is abelian.

**Problem:** Find $N$ if $G = S_3 $.

**Solution**: We have that $A_3$ is a normal subgroup of index 2, and it follows that $N$ is a subgroup of $A_3$.

$N = A_3$.

**My question:** Why does it follow that $N$ is a subgroup of $A_3$? Is that always the case, for when we have a normal subgroup of index $2$, any other normal subgroup must be a subgroup of the normal subgroup? I am aware that one can calculate all the subgroups of $S_3$ and find that it's only nontrivial normal subgroup is $A_3$.

Best regards

Comment: The general fact is that $N$ is the smallest normal subgroup that leads to an abelian quotient.

Comment: Maybe GAP helps.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Can you please elaborate?